# (SQL) How to manage the values in a column that were imported with the currency symbol?

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery, currency

I'm taking the Google Data Analytics course. In this course, they teach us about SQL using BigQuery. However, I didn't want to add a paying method, so instead of using BigQuery I'm using MySQL Server and MySQL Workbench. So far, I came across some problems. However, I was able to handle them, except for one.

Well, I'm working with a .csv file that contains infos about movies, such as movie titles, casting, directors, release dates, genres, budgets and revenues. In this course, when the teacher uploads the .csv file into BigQuery, it already recognizes that the values in "budget" and "revenue" columns are referent to a currency. However, when I uploaded this file into MySQL, it understands those values as TEXT, because they're containing a currency symbol ($) in each one of the fields. This situation is making it impossible to me to sort the fields according to the ammount of budget or revenue. How can I fix it?

My ideas:

> is there anyway I could simply update the values in this columns, removing the currency symbol ($)?
> is there anyway I could import the .csv file again in a way MySQL would understand what those values are about?

@Barman

I'm really new in SQL. I tried:
`SELECT budget = REPLACE(@budget, '$', '') FROM customer_data.movie_data;` as a result, MySQL showed me 508 rows with a NULL value.

@Barman
Now I tried the following query:

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE(budget, '$', '') AS new_budget
FROM customer_data.movie_data
```

As result, MySQL showed me all rows without the currency symbol. However, how can I update the "budget" column with this new info?

**FINAL ANSWER** // **FINAL EDITION**:

```
UPDATE customer_data.movie_data
SET 
    revenue = REPLACE(revenue, '$', ''),
    budget = REPLACE(budget, '$', ''),
    budget = REPLACE (budget, ',', ''),
    revenue = REPLACE(revenue, ',', '');
```

**Then > alter table > TEXT to DECIMAL (40,2) and that's it!
I guess there's no way without some work to be done. I hope it will help someone!**

Comment: `LOAD DATA INFILE` allows you to process the value from the CSV file before inserting it into the table. See the use of `@variable` in the column list. So you can do `budget = REPLACE(@budget, '$', '')`

Comment: Don't put code in comments, edit the question and use a code block so it will be formatted readably.

Comment: OK! I'm sorry about that.

Comment: `UPDATE movie_data SET budget = REPLACE(budget, '$', '')` But I thought you wanted to remove the `$` when importing the CSV file, so you can declare it as a numeric column.

Comment: I did prefer that way. However I didn't understand how to do it.

Comment: Did you read the `LOAD DATA INFILE` documentation and try to figure out, or do you expect me to write it for you?

Comment: I did read it. It was challenging to understand. I was using the Import Wizard to import the .csv file. As I said, I'm really new in this. Anyway, thank you for your attention. I was able to update the files as you taught me. Unfortunately, in "alter table", MySQL Workbench didn't allow me to transform the datatype into float. Anyway, thanks, man. And I'm sorry if somehow it looked like I was demanding any answers. My English is far from great.

Comment: You're probably not going to be able to do it with a wizard, but I'm not really familiar with them.

Comment: If you've come up with a solution you should post the solution was an answer, not edit it into your question. It's fine to answer your own question.

Comment: I suppose you could have used find/replace in the CSV file to replace $ with '' before the import.  or used notepad++ to remove the $ or similar. The find and replace options will remove all $ so if some text has it; you'd end up replacing it.  Notepad++ gives you some more flexability.

Comment: @xQbert oh i didn't know that program! that is sure a great idea! i'll try it right now!

Comment: @xQbert it turned out to be a good way to remove the $ symbol. However, I don't think it is a good way to remove the commas (that are separating the numbers - for instance $1,000,000.00) because I think it would remove ALL the commas in the .CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

**FINAL ANSWER // FINAL EDITION:**

```
UPDATE customer_data.movie_data SET 
    revenue = REPLACE(revenue, '$', ''),
    budget = REPLACE(budget, '$', ''),
    budget = REPLACE (budget, ',', ''),
    revenue = REPLACE(revenue, ',', '');
```

Then > alter table > TEXT to DECIMAL (40,2) and that's it! I guess there's no way without some work to be done. I hope it will help someone!